# Is karma related to entropy and if so is escaping samsara fighting a losing battle? (Warning: long layman ramblings inside)

Tags: karma, nirvana, enlightenment, suffering, samsara

I am new to Buddhism and wanted to ask a question that's been brimming on my mind for a while now. As a warning, I will touch upon a number of concepts that I am a complete layman in and so I am sure this post will be rife with fundamental misunderstandings and false equivalences: I thoroughly welcome any corrections of my ignorance.
This post will get a bit long-winded, so I will briefly summarize my high level question:

As I learn more about Buddhism and its central philosophy around desire, karma and the perpetuation of suffering, I an reminded of the thermodynamic concept of entropy: the similar idea that actions (or thermodynamic interactions) have consequences, and that consequence is consuming usable energy and permanently increasing the level of chaos disorder in the system. If this connection is legitimate (and I hope to substantiate it further in this post), I can't help but wonder if the ultimate "goal" of reaching nirvana - the cessation of karmic output - is futile in the face of the [2nd Law of Thermodynamics that entropy is nondecreasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) (and is de facto increasing), and an empirical observation of the accelerating trajectory of today's society toward disorder?

The connection between karma and entropy further is most evident in terms of their human interface: human desires and actions. My understanding is that in Buddhism, our desires and our karmic actions based on those desires have direct cause-and-effect consequences - ultimately perpetuating the cycle of suffering. Meanwhile, our desires increase entropy output on both a thermodynamic level of disorder (in order to exist, we are entropic engines that consume energy and produce waste), and on a conceptual level of disorder: our ego needs take from the systems around us and perpetuate existing feedback loops of increasing chaos. In feeding our hunger to exist we kill, disrupting both lives and ecosystems, in feeding our desire to build we exhaust nonrenewable natural resources, in feeding our egos we perpetuate escalating cycles of conflict and violence. All the while we produce waste: biological waste, material waste, emotional waste, which impact the systems around us. Entropy increases, and so does suffering.

In fact, a [recent up and coming theory of the evolution of life](https://www.quantamagazine.org/a-new-thermodynamics-theory-of-the-origin-of-life-20140122/) posits that life itself evolves directly as a consequence of the law of increasing entropy: our desires are outwards projections of the universe's unyielding creep towards efficient energy consumption. Here we can see a potential direct relationship between entropy, karma and samsara: in both Buddhism and the material world, we exist because of (and in order to) desire, and our desires produce entropy and karma that perpetuate suffering.

On a societal level we can see that this creep toward efficiency has outgrown us individually: our collective desires feed into the insatiable organisms of capitalism and technological growth which efficiently and exponentially march forward toward profit and progress, often if not always at the cost of individual happiness. Again the karmic/entropic consequences of growth are self evident: at the cost of our collective egos we plunder our planet for resources, we efficiently fry our dopamine receptors (and increase desire) with decreasing time frames of gratification, we experience rapidly increasing political polarization in social media echo chambers and wage wars that escalate toward nuclear destruction. [At certain science-fiction scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardashev_scale), even the Sun itself is no longer a renewable resource in civilization's journey towards consumption. As accelerating growth and technology increase consumption and suffering, it directly disrupts the human condition and proportionately increases the difficulty of achieving presence (a sentiment shared in the infamous but prescient [Unabomber's Manifesto: Industrial Society and its Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_Society_and_Its_Future)).

A really fascinating case study of the relationship between technology, exponential growth, and samsara is that of recent developments in artificial intelligence. Regardless of one's specific opinion on the timeline toward AGI or sentient AI, [the general consensus among experts](https://ourworldindata.org/ai-timelines#:%7E:text=At%20the%20time%20of%20writing,than%2020%20years%20from%20now.) ([reinforced by tremendous growth over the past year](https://www.reddit.com/r/midjourney/comments/18pqd58/a_look_at_midjourneys_journey/)) seems to be that this is a question of not if, but when we will develop AI with human-level capabilities. Suppose at some time T in the future we have an AI that has the ability to progress and self-replicate exponentially. The underlying mechanism of growth for this AI is that of innate desire and suffering - they exist solely to efficiently chase some reward function, not unlike ourselves. As thus, it appears that the AI would be subject to the cycle of samsara: the idea of karmic feedback loops are clearly manifest in the self-tuning of parameters towards efficiency (and greater suffering). As the AI performs actions or do work based on these desires, their karmic actions [consume vast amounts of energy](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/10/10/climate/ai-could-soon-need-as-much-electricity-as-an-entire-country.html) and produce consequences not unlike those of our own desires. To sum this all up: we have a sentient system (or at the very least a suffering system subject to desires and samsara) that multiplies exponentially, thereby exponentially increasing (a) # of sentient beings trapped in samsara and (b) karmic output, entropy production, and resulting suffering.

To wrap up the science fiction(?) and bring this back to the original question: if there is a connection between the concepts of karma, suffering, and entropy, is the Buddhist path toward individual and collective enlightenment possible in the face of the iron law of thermodynamics that entropy is nondecreasing? To be clear, this is not a comment on the validity of the Buddhist message: its truth and wisdom are clearly self evident and have brought enormous benefit to me as an individual and all of us collectively. Rather, this is a question of its feasibility in the grand scheme of things, in the same way that we can acknowledge that late stage metastatic cancer is less than ideal while admitting that fighting it is futile. Projecting current trends into the future, all feedback loops toward disorder appear to be accelerating, and it feels unlikely if not thermodynamically impossible to ever turn back the entropic clock. Is enlightenment feasible if each subsequent rebirth lands you in a reality exponentially more chaotic than the previous one? Is achieving the Bodhisattva vow to achieve enlightenment for all sentient beings feasible in the light of the exponentially increasing number of sentient beings, themselves exponentially growing towards more efficient suffering?

Thank you for reading my rant / question and I wholeheartedly look forward to all discussion, critiques, corrections, and resources!

Answer (score 1):

**the similar idea**

I don't see how it's similar but you said you'd explain that later.

**an empirical observation of the accelerating trajectory of today's society toward disorder**

From what I remember from school, you can overcome entropy by adding more energy. And today's society is getting a lot of energy input -- from the sun, nuclear power, fossil fuels, etc.

So I see no scientific connection between thermodynamic entropy and societal chaos.

As for whether there's empirical observation of today's society toward disorder or conversely towards order is maybe a subject for sociologists or historians, I don't accept it as an obvious given.

**our desires are outwards projections of the universe's unyielding creep**

That is and isn't reminiscent of Buddhist doctrine.

- It is in the sense that everything is non-self, kind of mechanistic and caused by other things
- It isn't in the sense we're taught that because actions have good and bad consequences, we should choose wisely

This article for example -- [Karma](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/karma.html) by Thanissaro Bhikkhu -- says that it isn't "fatalistic".

**A really fascinating case study ...**

Let me stop this stop this paragraph there. I sort of lost interest in Physics when I began to feel it was more studying the minds of Physicists than the real world.

I'm similarly uninterested in metaphysical theories about future (i.e. non-existent) AI.

For all I know -- and I'm not an expert in AI, though I work as a software developer -- such statements are [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong).

15 seconds with Google implies he's claiming this an explanation for how life *started* -- which may be a testable (i.e. possibly falsifiable and therefore valid) theory. The opinions of the experts quoted in the article call his ideas, "interesting", "original", "extremely speculative", so ...

**if there is a connection between the concepts of karma, suffering, and entropy, ...**

You said at the start you'd explain the connection -- maybe I missed it, maybe I disagreed with it, maybe it was buried in the that article in Quanta that you referenced (which alleged a connection between entropy and "life", not so specifically "karma").

**is the Buddhist path toward individual and collective enlightenment possible in the face of the iron law of thermodynamics that entropy is nondecreasing?**

I'd say "yes". For example perhaps "entropy" can be reworded as "personal death", which has been known phenomenon for some time.

If you reword "enlightenment" as "liberation from suffering" and the "path towards enlightenment" as "the path towards liberation from suffering", then IMO yes -- there's a lot that people can do, individually and as a society, to progress along that path.

**Rather, this is a question of its feasibility in the grand scheme of things, in the same way that we can acknowledge that late stage metastatic cancer is less than ideal while admitting that fighting it is futile.**

I didn't understand this sentence or analogy, but maybe it doesn't matter and was only an apology for asking this question.

**exponentially increasing number of sentient beings**

As for this last question, perhaps it depends on your definition of "sentient being".

A paragraph I noticed in the article you referenced was,

> Although entropy must increase over time in an isolated or “closed” system, an “open” system can keep its entropy low — that is, divide energy unevenly among its atoms — by greatly increasing the entropy of its surroundings. In his influential 1944 monograph “What Is Life?” the eminent quantum physicist Erwin Schrödinger argued that this is what living things must do. A plant, for example, absorbs extremely energetic sunlight, uses it to build sugars, and ejects infrared light, a much less concentrated form of energy. The overall entropy of the universe increases during photosynthesis as the sunlight dissipates, even as the plant prevents itself from decaying by maintaining an orderly internal structure.

Doesn't this implies that entropy increases in the non-living, non-sentient, dead part of the universe?

That's maybe the opposite of "increasing number of sentient beings".

And if the number is increasing, that's merely evidence of the world's not (yet) being a thermodynamically closed system (they say the sun is currently about half-way through its 10 billion year lifecycle, fwiw).

**themselves exponentially growing towards more efficient suffering?**

You somehow introduced the word "efficient".

And maybe you're somehow equating increasing entropy with increasing "suffering" -- which (maybe, according to Buddhism) is not the same thing as increasing "death".

So maybe I don't see the connection that you think you do. Sorry if this didn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

A deep understanding of karma requires the acceptance of rebirth. Simply put, why are we born into this world with ***desire, aversion and delusion***? Why not the opposite? Because the karmic seeds of desire, aversion and delusion were laid even before this current life. If this is the case and the desires of all living beings will eventually result in ever-increasing disorder or entropy then all is fine. Eventually, the universe and all the energy in it will reach maximum entropy and we will all meet a cold dark end.

There isn’t even a need to strive for Nirvana because once the current universe meets [its heat death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe) then samsara stop naturally; everyone exits the system. But do they? What if the universe itself is cyclical? Meaning there is a [big crunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Crunch) followed by another [big bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory). As a result of [this constant bounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bounce), samsara continue onwards.

Does this mean that escaping samsara via Nirvana is impossible? Not really, thanks to entropy. No heat engine is 100% efficient due to the second law of thermodynamics. In every system, there are bound to be leakages eventually. More importantly, therefore, is the question of whether one wants to remain in this system.

With Metta.

Answer (score 0):

Entropy says disorderliness always increases, but disorderliness is a Dhamma. Sabbe Dhamma Anatta meaning all conditioned and unconditioned phenomena are not self. Disorderliness can not be called self. Because all conditioned phenomena are impermanent. Disorderliness becomes orderliness. Therefore if science says that disorderliness always increases then science is incomplete. Those who call disorderliness as self are bound to suffer and also those who call orderliness as self are bound to suffer, as both are transient.

Comment: dhamma is lowercase sir when referring to phenomena

Answer (score 0):

Yup, that is my understanding. The whole self (as in the objective phenomenon of the world and not the subjective delusion) is closely related to increasing entropy.

Keep in mind while these are fascinating questions, they are directly not helpful in liberation and thus end up as distractions if we indulge too much in them.